In Austria once a child is 18 can maintainence be paid directly to the child rather than the parent with whom they abide?
In Austria it is mandatory for a parent to pay maintenance even after the child is 18 until they are self supporting. My question is whether this money can be paid directly to the child rather than the custodial parent?

Is there are divorce decree or child support order or separation agreement that provides any clarity on that issue?

The law states that maintenance needs to be paid but is unclear on who should be the recipient after the child turns 18.

Even if the law itself is unclear, the specific court order in question might be more clear.
